# No se clona correctamente mi proyecto desde Gitlab: 'fatal: write error: Invalid argument'

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash, git-clone

Tengo que clonar un proyecto desde GitLab en mi local para trabajar a través de GitBash pero al clonarlo salta el siguiente error:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 4085, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4085/4085), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2642/2642), done.
fatal: write error: Invalid argument 21.00 MiB | 70.00 KiB/s
fatal: write error: Invalid argument
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Aparentemente no existe ningún problema relacionado ni con las credenciales ni con los permisos de acceso, el 'keygen' pasa correctamente y la 'ssh-key' es correcta.

¿cómo puedo salvar este error?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a este problema, basta con incluir la siguiente instrucción de 'git' antes de comenzar con el proceso de clonado:

```
  git config --global core.compression 0
```

Esta instrucción lo que hace es "apagar" o cancelar la compresión y permitir que el proceso se finalice correctamente saltándose el error que anteriormente daba. Una vez dada está instrucción se puede hacer sin problema:

```
 git clone "el repositorio que corresponda"
```